# Mass edit individual attribute in Active Directory from source data

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, editing

At work we just got a whole new range of phone numbers. This means that every phonenumber is changed. This needs to be reflected in our Active Directory for easy access and other dependancies. There is a simple excel file which includes the following attributes (phonenumber) (extension) (first lastname). The extension can be deleted since it is included in the main number, so that is not important. Unfortunately the source file does not include an UPN.

I have looked at options to do this, a whole bunch of them were suggested [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/233916-active-directory-mass-edit-tool). However, all those that could possible do what we need are based on installed software. This is however not an option on our server.

Therefore my question is, is there a way to mass edit everything in a command promt or powershell? I would like to do something like this, but then something for unique attributes for specified users;

```
get-aduser -filter { city -like 'Glitter*' } | set-aduser -city 'Las Vegas' -PostalCode 89123 –PassThru
```

([reference](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/active_directory-powershell-administrative_permissions-cmdlet-domain_administrators,2-268.html))

Comment: First name and last name are not guaranteed unique. Are you happy assuming they are? I shall guess the sample was copied from somewhere since you are not trying to change city or postal code

Comment: Yep, you definitely need to have UPN in that file of yours

Comment: As you can see I referenced to where i got the postal code from. The reason I posted that is because that is something I could run on the server. But it is indeed different because  need individual information. The displayname is unique, No-one has the same total name.

But to export the UPN names and then add it to the excel file and exclude non existent names is going to take even longer than manually editting them probably. I'm talking about 100 records for now, more to follow later.

Comment: Yep... If I read the link I would have seen that. Display name is __not__ what you have in your sample file. Is that what we are to assume (first lastname) is?

Comment: I don't like working with the Display Name either, but it is the closest attritube to something I could run against in AD. First and last name only are not unique enough and as said, the source file doesn't contain the UPN.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source file is set up like it is in your question this should be a good start for what you need. Convert your source file to a csv to save you some headache. This assumes that the first line is `first lastname,phonenumber,extension`. Order does not matter.

```psh
# Collect the source data as a powershell object we can process in a loop
$list = Import-CSV "C:\temp\sourcedata.csv"

# Process each user individually
ForEach($user in $list){
    # Get the user matching the display name
    $results = Get-ADUser -filter "DisplayName -eq '$($user."First LastName")'"

    # If a user was returned set the phone number
    If($results){
        $results | Set-ADUser -OfficePhone $user.phonenumber -WhatIf
    } Else {
        Write-Warning "$($user.'First LastName') not found"
    }
}
```

We use `Get-ADUser` to find the "one" user and make changes based the record in your source file.  You can leave `-Whatif` in there for testing. PowerShell will tell you it is editing so you can get a feel for what is happening. We are assuming `-OfficePhone` is the attribute you are updating.

Comment: Seems like it could work indeed. Will report back after some tests!

Comment: @Ircghost check my update. Forgot to mention about you source file.